# Spring Batch Job dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am new to Spring Batch. I have a requirement to schedule multiple jobs  where one job is dependent on completion of other job. In Spring Batch I found that it is very easy to put step dependency. Is there any way to make one job dependent on other job?

Comment: Why can't you make it a step?

Comment: Brian, I have couple of steps need to run one after another in both the jobs. And then the jobs also need to run one after another.

Comment: I do not think it's possible to chain jobs.  At least not from what I can find in the documentation.  I would suggest chaining steps.  If necessary, you can re-use steps in different jobs.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Batch does not provide a way to have dependency between jobs. However ideal way to achieve this is how you are invoking the jobs. This can be easily achieved using Quartz scheduler.

Or can be done like this.

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(config);
JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
Job job1 = (Job) context.getBean("testJob");
Job job2 = (Job) context.getBean("testJob2");


JobExecution execution1 = jobLauncher.run(job1, new JobParameters());
System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution1.getStatus());
if(execution1.getStatus()==0){
     JobExecution execution2 = jobLauncher.run(job2, new JobParameters());
     System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution2.getStatus());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `JobExecutionListener.afterJob` and run the other job based on the outcome of the first. See the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/JobExecutionListener.html) for more details.

But it might make more sense to configure a new job that encompasses all these steps and re-uses the existing steps in that job.